# WSO2IS on smartphone

Tags: facebook, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I want to use wso2is to manage users account from multiple webapps and smartphone applications.
I also need Facebook federated authenticator with provisionning to my user store.

I found (hardly) how to make it work, especially the direct call to wso2is to provide FB redirection, but how can I do it for smartphone ?

I found this article about native mobile apps but it does not explain how to connect to FB via wso2is :

http://wso2.com/library/articles/2014/07/sso-for-native-mobile-applications-with-wso2-identity-server/

and the sdk provided (https://github.com/GayanM/android-idp-sdk) doesn't seem very popular nor maintained...

Regards,